# JS/Ajax to pass checkbox selections to a POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax

It's been suggested to me to use a linting tool to help debug javascript/ajax.  So i've installed Linter with Atom with the JCJS package and on the following code it's giving me a single error that I'm struggling to find a solution to.  I've commented the errors linter is showing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var SelectedItems = [];
    $('.checkbox').click(function () {
        var SelectedItems = $(this).val();
        var index = SelectedItems.indexOf(SelectedItems);
        if (index == -1)
        {
          SelectedItems.push(SelectedItems);
        }        else {
          SelectedItems.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });

    $('#submit-button').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/requestaccess/',
            data: JSON.stringify({ report_id: SelectedItems }),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
            }  //missing comma before closing curly brace
          });
      });
  });
```

If I add a common before the curly brace on line 22 it gives me an unexpected token error.

I'm struggling to get my code to work to pull in the check box selections in a Django web application on a key field report_id.

A small portion of my code to simply the HTML is the following:

```
  <form action = "">
                <div class="row">
                <h3>All Applications</h3>

                        <ul>
                        {% for app in allgrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>

                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `invalid line break` might refer to a line break character. http://jscs.info/rule/validateLineBreaks.html

Comment: for "extra quotes for key"  you can try `data: JSON.stringify({ report_id: SelectedItems })`

Comment: fixed the extra quotes for key with JSON.stringify.

Comment: The function isn't working correctly though, i'm thinking it might be my url: I followed the example in the book, but in Django URL's are different. Like in the following HREF in the HTML.               <a href="{% url 'requestaccess' %}" />  when I add {% url 'requestaccess' %} it gives me expected.   It's defined as  url(r'^requestaccess/$', views.requestaccess, name='requestaccess')  When I state not working correctly, my python console shows no POST request.

Comment: if you use the dev console in your browser and inspect the link does it show the correct URL in the `href` ? Also does the submit event `$('#submit-button').click(function (event) {`  even get called when you click the submit button?